# Can I turn off power save function of emulator?

Tags: android

Whenever I execute my app, I have to click one more time to brighten emulator screen.
Is there any way I can turn off power save function of emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Setting->Display->Screen timeout-->30 minutes(max).  This will keep your screen from dimming in emulator.